# Activate and run a jQuery script using a value from a Django view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

On a Django template I have a form that allows users to upload images to a remote server. Once the upload is complete, the server returns the url to the image to my Django view. I have this image url as a string in my view.

How can I use this url to activate and be used in a jQuery script? I'd like to append it a form without refreshing the page. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to be returning a JsonResponse and using an Ajax sciprt, but I am pretty new to this and am having a hard time getting it working. I'm not getting any errors from the Ajax script, and I can see the img_url is in the JsonResponse content, but when I upload a file, nothing happens. This is the relevant bits to what I have so far:

Django View:

```
    else:
        img_form = forms.PostImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if img_form.is_valid():
            new_img = models.PostImage.objects.create(post=post)
            new_img.file = request.FILES['file']
            new_img.save()
            img_url = new_img.file.url
        return JsonResponse({'img_url': img_url})
```

HTML/Ajax:

```
<script>
function append_form() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/blogs/{{topic}}/{{post_url}}/edit_post/",
      data: {},
      success: function(){
        var contentField = $("#myPostForm textarea[name=content]");
        contentField.val( contentField.val() + "<img src='" + data.img_url + "' >" );
      }
    })
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the JSON result to your success function like so:

```
success: function(resultData){
    var contentField = $("#myPostForm textarea[name=content]");
    contentField.val( contentField.val() + "<img src='" + resultData.img_url + "' >" );
  }
```

Forthermore, you can delete the `data: {},` line from your AJAX request since you aren't passing anything to your API. That line is the data you would be passing. The parameter in the success function is the data you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change you suggested. However, it still doesn't want to work. Even if I put an alert command in the function to test if it is running, nothing comes up. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the append_form function isn't being called at all. console.log statements do not print inside the function (both the append_form and the success function). Is there a way to force this to run?